# plot only specific columns in gnuplot

Tags: bash, gnuplot

I have a csv file as show below and i want to plot S(on x axis) and B(axis).How do i generate a plot of lines with gnuplot.

```
    Test_Image,Original_Size
    red-room.png,918394
    Q,S,B,S,C,R
    0,1021763,0.121086,0.00001459,-11.26,-222.18
    1,1061763,0.125086,0.00001459,-11.26,-222.18
    2,1051763,0.121086,0.00001459,-11.26,-222.18
    3,1041763,0.121086,0.00001459,-11.26,-222.18
    4,986461,0.151573,0.00003318,-7.63,-211.67
    5,955766,0.160869,0.00005782,-4.07,-201.37
```

Basically i need to a way to tell gnuplot to ignore the first 3 rows and plot the 2rd and 3rd column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell gnuplot that fields are delimited by commas and that it should plot columns 2 and 3:

```
set datafile separator comma
plot "data.csv" using 2:3 w lp
```

Gnuplot will ignore the first three lines automatically.

Comment: separator comma did the job!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the data as it is read in (without affecting your input file) like this:

```
plot 'awk -F, "NR>3{print $2,$3}" data.csv |' using ...
```

That says to print fields 2 and 3 of lines where line number is greater than 3 of your input file `data.csv`.

You can experiment with the `awk` command stand-alone in the Terminal to test it outside of `gnuplot`:

```
awk -F, 'NR>3{print $2, $3}' data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In user8153's answer gnuplot will ignore the first 3 lines because they contain strings not numbers. If column 2 and 3 would contain some numbers they would be plotted.

So, a slightly different way would be

- explicitly skip 2 rows
- specify the columns **via header strings** `"S"` and `"B"`. With this you don't even have to care whether your data is in column 2 und 3 or maybe somewhere else. And even files with different column number or order, but same headers would be plotted correctly.

**Script:**

```
### select columns via header strings
reset session

$Data <<EOD
Test_Image,Original_Size
red-room.png,918394
Q,S,B,S,C,R
0,1021763,0.121086,0.00001459,-11.26,-222.18
1,1061763,0.125086,0.00001459,-11.26,-222.18
2,1051763,0.121086,0.00001459,-11.26,-222.18
3,1041763,0.121086,0.00001459,-11.26,-222.18
4,986461,0.151573,0.00003318,-7.63,-211.67
5,955766,0.160869,0.00005782,-4.07,-201.37
EOD

set datafile separator comma

plot $Data u "S":"B" skip 2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]